# Place something in the middle of a hphantom (more or less)

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I have a part of a formula like

```
$\det (T + S + Z)$.
```

For alignment purposes, I want to create a horizontal space of exactly the width of this formula. But in the middle of this space, I want to display something else (e.g. x).

What I want to achieve as output is

```
(-- some crap --) det (T + S + Z) (some other crap)% <- this line should be invisible

(-- some crap --)        x        (some other crap),
```

but the first line should **not** be shown, I only displayed it here to indicate the desired formatting, i.e. the horizontal coordinate of the "x" should be exactly the middle of "det (T + S + Z)" in the first line.

All of this takes place in a "displayed math environment", i.e. inside of \[ \].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\mathmakebox` of `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% also loads amsmath
\usepackage{calc}% for \widthof

\newcommand{\centerto}[2]{%
  \mathmakebox[\widthof{$\displaystyle#2$}]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\det(T+S+Z)&=42\\
\centerto{x}{\det(T+S+Z)}&=1003
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note I used `align` just to show the centering to the requested width.